# Is there a way to use the media query (hover: hover) in the opposite way, so that it matches hover-less devices?

Tags: css, media-queries

would like to define a media query that matches ipad & co.

with

```
@media (hover: hover)
{
   .. applies to desktop
}
```

i can define a media query that applies to desktop browsers (roughly speaking).
i would like to define the opposite however, a media query that applies for devices where hover = false.

tried

```
@media (hover: false)
```

but that dies not work. also

```
@media not (hover: hover)
```

does not work as it is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (hover: none)
```

does it.

https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-5/#hover